# MongoDB on Solaris 10 undefined symbol

Tags: mongodb, solaris

we want to use MongoDB for one of our projects.
According to best practices, the query router of a sharded cluster shall stay with the app servers (Java). These are running on Solaris 10 (Intel, 64bit).

I downloaded the Solaris build 2.4.9, added thr 64bit stdc++ lib to LD_LIBRARY_PATH and tried to start the query router.
It fails with undefined symbol: *ZNSt3tr18*_detail12__prime_listE .

Does anyone know how to solve this without compiling everything on our own?

Thanks & Regards,
Dirk

Comment: Can you paste the error message in the logs, the full stack trace and the output of "uname -a" of the system?

Comment: Hi Linda,
that's what happens:
don101:~\> /cm/mongodb/mongodb/bin/mongo
ld.so.1: mongo: fatal: relocation error: file /opt/data/cm/mongodb/mongodb-sunos5-x86_64-2.4.9/bin/mongo: symbol _ZNSt3tr18__detail12__prime_listE: referenced symbol not found
Killed

it happens for both SunOS 5.10 and SunOS 5.11:
SunOS BTO1S04CAS0S 5.10 Generic_148889-01 i86pc i386 i86pc
SunOS BTO1A01GKS0S 5.11 11.1 i86pc i386 i86pc

Thanks & Regards,
Dirk